# POI's setColumnWidth -- character width?

Tags: java, excel, width, apache-poi

> `public void setColumnWidth(int columnIndex,
>                     int width)`
>
> Set the width (in units of 1/256th of a character width)

1/256th the width of **WHICH CHARACTER**? Different characters have different widths. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see the Javadoc of HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth() method, it has the explanation of the Character width. Pasting the excerpt below:

> Character width is defined as the maximum digit width of the numbers
>   0, 1, 2, ... 9 as rendered using the default font (first font in the
>   workbook).  Unless you are using a very special font, the default
>   character is '0' (zero), this is true for Arial (default font font in
>   HSSF) and Calibri (default font in XSSF)

Refer link: [http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth(int, int)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Okay, thanks! The same source I quoted says "Using the Calibri font as an example, the maximum digit width of 11 point font size is 7 pixels." However, the FontMetrics class returns a value of 6 for the width of 0 using Calibri, 11pt. Any idea as to what's causing this discrepancy?